# Dynamically Set SubForm Validators from the Parent component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

I've been creating reuseable subforms in Angular 8, and using the `FormGroupDirective` to get a reference of the parent `FormGroup` for the child is quite easy to accomplish, but I'm having a hard time figure out how to dynamically set the validators on the child form from the parent.

Using `ngAfterViewInit` I can see the form controls of the child forms have been added to the parent, but I can't seem to update the default child form validators directly from the parent.

```js
// PARENT COMPONENT
public ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Form controls have been applied to the form group
  console.log('ngAfterViewInit', this.form.value);

  // BUT the validators of profile form aren't being set?
  this.form.get('profile').get('description').setValidators([Validators.required]);
}
```

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sub-form-validations?embed=1&file=src/app/page/page.component.ts) of my example code.  All the fields except the profile description is a required field and has a default value.  So without any changes being made to the validators the form will pass validations on submission and output **VALID** in the console.  In `ngAfterViewInit` I set the description fields validator to be required, which should prevent the form from being submitted and output **INVALID** in the console, but it still submits and outputs **VALID**.

Is it possible to dynamically set the validators of a subform without passing them in via `@Input` bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you just have to use `updateValueAndValidity` on the form control that was changed.

```js
this.form.get('profile').get('description').updateValueAndValidity();
```

So it looks like this in the end:

```js
public ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Form controls will now exist
  console.log('ngAfterViewInit', this.form.value);

  // BUT the validators of the profile form should not allow submission if set to required, and they do?

  this.form.get('profile').get('description').setValidators([Validators.required]);
  this.form.get('profile').get('description').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

When you do this you'll get an error in the console that says:

```js
ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.
```

Which can be overcome by using `ChangeDetectorRef` and invoking `this.changeDetector.detectChanges()`, or by updating the parent component's change detection strategy to be `ChagneDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

```js
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

// Removed for brevity

public ngAfterViewInit() {
  const descControl = this.form.get('profile').get('description');
  descControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
  descControl.updateValueAndValidity();

  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
  // Removed for brevity

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const descControl = this.form.get('profile').get('description');
    descControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    descControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```